# Flutter Drawer функция hide/show

Tags: flutter

Пытаюсь сделать админку в WebApp flutter. Родной drawer при открытии покрывает полностью контент, я хочу сделать его всегда открытым и при нажатий на иконку закрывать. Как сделать функцию hide/show ? 
код:

```
class AdminPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AdminPage createState() => _AdminPage();
}

bool isColapsed = true;

class _AdminPage extends State<AdminPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Builder(
            builder: (context) => IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer())),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        actions: <Widget>[IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: () {})],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.amberAccent,
            child: Center(
              child: Text('content'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Переделанный виджет

```
    class SideMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SideMenuState createState() => _SideMenuState();
}

bool isSideBarOpened = true;
final _animationDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 500);

class _SideMenuState extends State<SideMenu> {
  Widget widgetForBody = FirstPage();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return AnimatedPositioned(
      duration: _animationDuration,
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      left: isSideBarOpened ? 0 : -300,
      right: isSideBarOpened ? 0 : screenWidth - 35,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: Container(
              width: 300.0,
              color: Colors.deepOrange,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('First Page'),
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        widgetForBody = FirstPage();
                      });
                    },
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment(0, -0.9),
            child: Container(
              width: 35,
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.deepOrange,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isSideBarOpened = !isSideBarOpened;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализация Drawer'a с анимацией появления и скрытия.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код так же можно воспроизвести в [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
​
/// Ширина Drawer'a
const double drawerWidth = 200;
/// Длительность анимации открытия и закрытия в миллисекундах
const Duration drawerAnimationDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 250);
​
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: AdminPage()));
}
​
class AdminPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AdminPage createState() => _AdminPage();
}
​
class _AdminPage extends State<AdminPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animation;
​
  @override
  void initState() {
    _animation = AnimationController(
      // Значение, определяющее открыт ли Drawer 
      // при первом появлении страницы. 0 - закрыт, 1 - открыт
      value: 1,
      vsync: this,
      duration: drawerAnimationDuration,
    );
​
    super.initState();
  }
​
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animation.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
​
  void _menuButtonPressed() {
    if (_animation.isAnimating) return;
    _animation.isCompleted ? _animation.reverse() : _animation.forward();
  }
​
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          SlideTransition(
            position: Tween<Offset>(
              begin: Offset(-1, 0),
              end: Offset.zero,
            ).animate(_animation),
            child: _buildMenu(),
          ),
          AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _animation,
            builder: (_, widget) => Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: drawerWidth * _animation.value),
              child: widget,
            ),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                AppBar(
                  title: Text('Admin panel'),
                  leading: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                    onPressed: _menuButtonPressed,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: _buildContent(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
​
  Widget _buildMenu() {
    return Container(
      width: drawerWidth,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(right: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[300])),
      ),
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(title: Text("Menu A")),
          ListTile(title: Text("Menu B")),
          ListTile(title: Text("Menu C")),
          ListTile(title: Text("Menu D")),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
​
  Widget _buildContent() {
    return Container(
      child: Center(child: Text('Content')),
      color: Colors.grey[200],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*По сути это уже не Drawer, а своя реализация меню...* Проверить можно в [DartPad'е](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: AdminPage()));
}

class AdminPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AdminPage createState() => _AdminPage();
}

class _AdminPage extends State<AdminPage> {
  bool _isMenuVisibility = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (context) => IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            onPressed: () => setState(() => (_isMenuVisibility)
                ? _isMenuVisibility = false
                : _isMenuVisibility = true),
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: () {}),
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.amberAccent,
            child: Center(
              child: Text('content'),
            ),
          ),
          menu(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget menu() {
    return Visibility(
      visible: _isMenuVisibility,
      child: Drawer(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Container(
              // width: 250.0,
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    child: ListView(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                          title: Text('page1'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: я сделал функцию с анимацией. Можете помочь с реализацией расширения и сужения контейнера. Саид меню всегда открыт и мне нужно чтоб правая часть была сужена, но когда закрываю меню чтоб расширялась.

Comment: @AndreyKhan вот пару ссылок на тему анимации, я думаю вам это подойдет: [medium](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-working-with-animatedsize-35253ff8f16a), [flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/animation/animated-container)